# Smart Thermostat without C on Heater

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I want to hook up my Honeywell rth9580wf to a natural gas garage heater that only has R, W, and G (not in use). It's currently hooked up to a standard battery powered Honeywell thermostat. I've read up on other posts for installing furnaces without C terminals, and gave it a try without luck. Here's what I did:
-Using a voltmeter I tested across the R terminal, and the red wire from the control board to the transformer. Each measures ~27V.
-No matter the heater's running state, I measure a constant ~27V at the R terminal and on the post of the transformer.
-Hooked up the G wire (which wasn't in use) to the R, and put this in the C on the thermostat. This did not power up.
-Was about to run a wire off the post on the transformer to the C, but held up before asking for advice.

I'd like some guidance I'd anyone can assist? Thank you.
[image][image]

Comment: How did you make the connection between the C wire from the transformer, the C wire heading off to the t-stat, and the C terminal on the heater's control board?

Comment: There isn't a C on the control board. All I tried was running a second tstat wire from the R down to the C on tstat.

Answer (score 1):

### You'll need to make a connection at that quick-connect with the red wire going to it

You see that quick-connect terminal you measured 27VAC from R to? That right there is where the control board connects to C, and can be used as a tap point for a C wire with the correct hardware.  In particular, you'll need a 6.3mm (0.25") *stacked* or *piggyback* quick-connect terminal (such as one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panduit-corp/EDV18-250P-Q/298-16710-ND/9491269)) that accepts 18AWG wire and appropriate crimping and stripping tools.

To assemble this:

1. Turn the power to the heater off.
2. Strip the end of the wire (blue is typical, but color doesn't matter) that you want to use for your C wire
3. Crimp the piggyback terminal onto the end of the C wire
4. Remove the red wire you measured 27V from R to from its terminal on the control board.  This is the C wire from the transformer.
5. Install the C wire piggyback terminal's female part onto the control board C terminal
6. Install the red C wire from the transformer onto the piggyback terminal's male part.
7. Turn the heater back on, and enjoy your new smart thermostat!

Comment: Thank you very much. So to confirm, am I going to the quick connect that is right next to the screw down R terminal (first picture) or the red on the transformer (second picture)?

Comment: @AdamEsquibel -- either one would *work*, although it'd probably be easier to use the one in the first picture from a wiring-neatness standpoint.

Comment: Ok, so I tried hooking a secondary wire as suggested onto the quick connect terminal and ran it to the C on the thermostat. I also hooked up the R and W wires. The thermostat did not power up. I tested voltage to confirm, and I'm reading about 27V off my new wire. I tried feeding off the transformer at the 24V terminal as well. No joy. Not sure what I could be doing wrong?